# Bootstrap pop up is not showing when we load second time

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal as below. I am using ng-show to trigger modal. Pop up is coming up when I load it first time and when I close the pop up and rerun second time pop up is not coming even if x.length is zero 0

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="modal" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;" role="dialog" ng-show="x.length==0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" >  
                                            <div class="modal-dialog" >

                                      <!-- Modal content-->
                                      <div class="modal-content">

                                        <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #428bca">
                                          <p ><font color="#FFFFFF">testing</font>
                                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="$('#modal').remove();">Close</button>
                                        </div>

                                      </div>

                                    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The $('#modal').remove() in your onclick will remove the modal from the DOM. Is that what you intended ? If you just want to dismiss it without removing it from the DOM, all you need is the data-dismiss="modal". Also, data-toggle="modal" and data-target="#modal" need to be on the element that triggers the modal, not sure why you have it on the modal itself.

Comment: @ami91 data-dismiss is not closing the pop up. I did tried that one.

Comment: Check my answer for possible ways of using the bootstrap modal. You will see how all I need to dismiss the modal is the data-dismiss ="modal" attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are creating the modal appears to be where the problem is. If you create the modal the way I've shown in the snippet, it will work. The data-toggle="modal" and data-target="#modal" need to be on the element that triggers the modal, and to close the modal, all you need is data-dismiss="modal". You can show or hide your trigger element with an ng-show condition.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.x = [];
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" ng-show="x.length==0">Click Here</div> 
  <div class="modal fade in" id="modal" role="dialog">  
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #428bca">
             <p><font color="#FFFFFF">testing</font></p>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you do not want a trigger element in your HTML like in the above example, then from your controller, you can show the modal using $('#modal').modal('show') and hide it using $('#modal').modal('hide'). Check out the modal options here - https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#usage

UPDATE:
Based on the comment, the following snippet shows how to show/hide the modal without having a trigger button. It uses the Bootstrap modal options listed above -

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.x = [];
    if($scope.x.length === 0){
      $("#modal").modal('show');
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="modal fade in" id="modal" role="dialog">  
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #428bca">
             <p><font color="#FFFFFF">testing</font></p>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont have any button to trigger modal. I have to check the result while page is loading and pop up the success. That's why I have choose ng-show option but, it seems like there is some problem with it.

Comment: @Kiran Check my updated answer accounting for your use case. The modal loads without needing a button to click and it can be dismissed just fine. Every time you reload the page with the code, the modal will come up.

Comment: It didn't work. I am experiencing same error as ng-show

Comment: @Kiran Then add a link to a JSFiddle or snippet showing what you are doing, so I can help you further. Without that, I do not know if you are doing it right or not.

Comment: The reason why it is not working is because there is watch on scope. If scope doesn't change it is not triggering the pop up. I might be silly but do you have any idea on how to unwatch a particular variable from scope

Comment: It is working great. The mistake I have done was added your code  before watch. That's why it didn't work. I moved the code after watch and triggered based on the result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem discussed, the modal does not work after the first time. Only refreshing the page will allow the functionality to work, once only. In my case, this was due to the way the js file was referenced in the html file (under @section Scripts):

I had a button  with an event to pop up the modal via the index.js file:

```
$(function () {
    $("#add-person").on('click', function () {
        $('.modal').modal();
    });
});
```

My HTML file:

```
<button id="add-person" class="button btn-success">Add People</button>
...
<div  class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 ...
</div><!-- /.modal -->
...
@section Scripts {
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
}
```

Note the non fully qualified
"js/index.js" reference. When I changed this to:

"/js/index.js" everything worked fine even after the first time.

This is because the URL constructed to find the index.js file was simply appending js/index.js to the current location  i.e /home/index/js/index.js instead of rerouting it to the root such as /js/index.js. It worked on the first attempt as at that point it was at the root so appending js/index.js pointed to the accurate location of the js file. Once the program passed the first round of the modal, it had already routed to /home/index so appending /js/index such as /home/index/js/index.js did not point to a valid path so it could not locate the js code to launch the modal.